# Getting an errror in flow "SELF_REFERENCE_FROM_FLOW"

Tags: visual-workflow, recordtriggeredflow

-We have two flow
In the first flow,

We delete invoices automatically when the opportunity event is deleted manually.

In the second flow,

We delete Opportunity Events automatically when the invoice is deleted manually.

when we debug flows

showing an error

```
The flow tried to delete these records: a1f8F000005hhY0QAI. 
This error occurred: SELF_REFERENCE_FROM_FLOW: 
Object (id = a1f8F000005hhY0) is currently in flow Opportunity_Event_Delete_Invoice, 
therefore it cannot recursively delete itself.
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: This error is commonly known as "recursion", it is due to the fact as you can see,
When you delete opportunity, you deleting invoice automatically. When you delete invoice, you are deleting opportunity automatically. 

That means, the flow keep repeating itself. For example, you delete opportunity, then the flow will be triggered to delete the invoice, than that flow will trigger the flow to delete the opportunity, which will trigger the flow to delete the invoice again. These process keep repeating, what is known as "recursion"

Comment: what is the solution for that?

Comment: have the first flow delegate its invoice deletion to an async operation